# Exclude "grouped" data from query

Tags: sql, postgresql, node-postgres

I have a table that looks like this (simplified):

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS records (
    user_id   uuid NOT NULL
    ts        timestamptz NOT NULL,
    op_type   text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, ts, op_type)
  );
```

I cannot for practical purposes change the PRIMARY KEY.

I'm trying to write a query that gets all `records` for a given `user_id` where, for a specific record, the `ts` and the `op_type` don't match an array of exclusions.

I'm not exactly sure of the right postgres terminology so let me see if this example makes my constraint clearer:

This array looks something like this (in JavaScript):

```
var excludes = [
  [DATE1, 'OP1'],
  [DATE2, 'OP2']
]
```

If, for a given user id, there are rows that look like this in the database:

```
             ts             |   op_type   
----------------------------+-------------
 DATE1                      | OP1
 DATE2                      | OP2
 DATE1                      | OP3
 DATE2                      | OP1
 OTHER DATE                 | OP1
 OTHER DATE                 | OP2
```

Then, with the `excludes` from above, I'd like to run a query that returns everything EXCEPT or the first two rows since they match exactly.

My attempt was to do this:

```
client.query(`
    SELECT * FROM records
      WHERE
        user_id = $1
        AND (ts, op_type) NOT IN ($2)
`, [userId, excluding])
```

But I get "input of anonymous composite types is not implemented". I'm not sure how to properly type `excluding` or if this is even the right way to do this.

Comment: There is no such thing as `$0`, variables starts with `$1`.

Comment: Typo in the question, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 3):

The query may look like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM records
WHERE user_id = 'a0eebc999c0b4ef8bb6d6bb9bd380a11'
AND (ts, op_type) NOT IN (('2016-01-01', 'OP1'), ('2016-01-02', 'OP2'));
```

so if you want to pass the conditions as a single parameter then `excluding` should be a string in the format:

```
('2016-01-01', 'OP1'), ('2016-01-02', 'OP2')
```

---

It seems that there is no simple way to pass the condition string into `query()` as a parameter. You can try to write a function to get the string in the correct format (I'm not a JS developer but this piece of code seems to work well):

```
excluding = function(exc) {
    var s = '(';
    for (var i = 0; i < exc.length; i++)
        s = s+ '(\''+ exc[i][0]+ '\',\''+ exc[i][1]+ '\'),';
    return s.slice(0, -1)+ ')';
};

var excludes = [
    ['2016-01-01', 'OP1'],
    ['2016-01-02', 'OP2']
];

// ...

client.query(
    'SELECT * FROM records '+
    'WHERE user_id = $1 '+
    'AND (ts, op_type) NOT IN ' + excluding(excludes),
    [userId])
```

Comment: That does seem to work -- any ideas on how to get the escaping of something like that to properly work with node-postgress? Any ideas about why the $1, $2 that I tried above is not working?

Comment: @AaronYodaiken that's because you didn't use `$1`, `$2`, you used `$0`, `$1`, which is incorrect, formatting variables start with `$1`.

Comment: @vitaly-t - This is an obvious mistake, but the question is how to format this kind of expression and properly pass it to `query()`.

Comment: Doesn't  the example above already provide all the details? What's the issue using it with `node-postgres`?

Comment: My solution is a kind of workaround, it's not very elegant. I would like to pass the string as a parameter instead of concatenating it with the query text.

Comment: Maybe you want too much formatting intelligence from the basic driver, which only supports simple variables.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was just curious, thanks for your tips.

Comment: @klin you are welcome! And if you want a really powerful query-formatting engine, among other things, then check out [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise).